# Changing the grammar of Python

Tags: python, grammar

Under the Grammar folder in Cpython there is a file Grammar which specifies the main grammar of the Python programming language. Does modifying this alter the main grammar of the programming language?

Comment: IIRC, there are like 6 different places you have to change, though I think most of them are auxiliary or documentation.

Comment: I remembered wrong. There are way more things to do; see [PEP 306](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0306/).

Answer (score 10):

The Grammar file controls the grammar of the language, but just modifying that is only one step of the process of changing the grammar. Many other files work closely with the grammar and need to be changed as well, such as `Parser/Python.asdl`, `Python/ast.c`, and `Python/compile.c`. The Python developer's guide has a [checklist](https://docs.python.org/devguide/grammar.html) of files that will likely need changing for any Python grammar change.